# Trouble Identifying Electrolytic Capacitor

Tags: capacitor, identification

I believe this is a 33pF ± 5% 100v SMD Electrolytic Capacitor, but I'm unsure because of the value of the second line:

[image: capacitor to which I'm having trouble identifying]

Am I reading it wrong? And where could I find such a replacement capacitor?

Comment: More likley 33 uF.  Electrolytic capacitors are normally over 1 uF, as the construction allows large values in a smaller volume than other technologies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Second line - capacitance in uF, third line - voltage. So, 33 uF 100V. Not sure about 1st line, it must be series name or code which describes structure type.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. When researching earlier, I found a site that gave some capacitor codes, which is what led me to believe the first line indicated 33pF ± 5%.

However the availability of the capacitor recommended, and its common use in a power supply for a monitor, makes me confident you're correct.

Comment: "330" follows the convention for resistors, such that it's 33 with a multiplier of (10^0).  331 would be 330uF, 332 would be 3300uF, etc.  You're right that, sight unseen, you'd think it's 33pf.  But being a large electrolytic cap, we know from experience that it's 33uF.

Comment: @gbarry is correct. Sometimes (specifically in the case of OSCON caps http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/1734354.pdf) the first line is the case size, but that's not the case here (pun intended).